# AWS Serverless Error - For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify, serverless, aws-code-deploy

During deploying serverless api to AWS lambda, I got an error message like this:

> Error: Failed to create managed resources: Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once

What is the solution and how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried rerunning this again after waiting for a bit? It's basically saying one of your stacks was rolled back (possibly because it failed building). Check the AWS CloudFormation console and you will see what exactly failed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  It's helpful if your title reflects your question.  Something like "Deployment of serverless api to AWS". We all hope that someone will help us when we are stuck.

Comment: You are not showing the real error - just a summary that there is an error somewhere. It's impossible to help you

Comment: did you solve? I faced the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the `CloudFormation` service page in the console. Look under `Stacks`.
There will be a stack with the status of `ROLLBACK_FAILED`.
If you look at the `Events` then you will see the cause.